# Regular expression to add dollar sign to amount inside of string

Tags: php, regex

I have some strings, each has one dollar amount in it (without the $) I would like to fish these amounts out via RegEx and add the $ to them.

Example strings:

> UPS GND (Ground) 5.88
>
> UPS 2DY (2 Day) 8.35
>
> UPS 1DY (Next Day) 15.65
>
> LTL COD 6.54

As you can see there are also some numbers in the service codes (sometimes) so I cant just look for numbers. I am horrible with RegEx!

Comment: Can it be guaranteed that they'll be in the format `##.##`? Can it be guaranteed that they'll be at the very end of the string?

Comment: The only guarantee is that it will be at the end of the string, but it could be 100.00, 1.54, 15.25, etc (I do not think the engine is possible of giving out a number in the thousands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following searchs for for one or more numbers, followed by a decimal, followed by two numbers:

```
preg_replace('/\d+\.\d{2}/', '$$0', $str)
```

Comment: this returns things like 11$8.06 and 1$5.65

Comment: thanks, working great...after I get the $ I can separate the price from the carrier easily as well...will accept when the time is up

Comment: +1 But I'd add some anchors and set multi-line mode like so: `'/\b\d+\.\d{2}[ \r]*$/m'`